# Which Advent is it?

Tags: code-golf, date

<sup>I know, a bit late.</sup>

## Challenge

Your challenge is, given a date, output if it's not an [Advent Sunday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advent_Sunday), or the Advent Sunday of the year.

## Rules

- The \$4^\text{th}\$ Advent is determined by the Sunday before Christmas day (the \$25^\text{th}\$ of December). The \$3^\text{rd}\$ Advent is the Sunday before the \$4^\text{th}\$ Advent, and so on until the \$1^\text{st}\$ Advent.
- If Christmas Day falls on a Sunday, then the Sunday before is still the \$4^\text{th}\$ Advent.
- Input will consist of day, month and year, as an iterable with any order, or a string, or 3 separate integers.
- Input will be a valid date, numerically and also calendrically.
- Output should be falsey (0 or Boolean False) if the date is not an Advent Sunday, or else an integer denoting which Advent Sunday it is.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

## Examples

```
[In]: [2, 12, 2021]
[Out]: 0

[In]: [6, 5, 2023]
[Out]: False

[In]: [12, 12, 2021]
[Out]: 3

[In]: [30, 11, 1997]
[Out]: 1

[In]: [25, 12, 2011]
[Out]: false

[In]: [21, 12, 3000]
[Out]: 4
```

Good Luck!

Comment: May we take input as 3 integers instead of a collection?

Comment: @chunes yes, 'll add that in

Answer (score 6):

## Excel, <s>71</s> 66 Bytes

<sup>Saved 5 bytes thanks to Taylor Raine</sup>

*Aside: At the time of posting, this answer has the smallest byte count. That is baffling. Score one for Excel's date handling, I guess.*

```
=LET(a,4-(INT(("12/23/"&YEAR(A1))/7)*7+1-A1)/7,(LEN(a)=1)*(a<5)*a)
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is. Returns a number 1-4 for advent Sundays and a 0 for all other dates.

```
LET(a,4-(INT(("12/23/"&YEAR(A1))/7)*7+1-A1)/7
```

The first part calculates which advent Sunday an input is and does most of the heavy lifting.

- `("12/23/"&YEAR(A1))` finds Christmas Eve Eve (CEE) in the year of the input. We find Eve Eve hear because it saves us some extra bytes of adjustment later.
- `INT(~/7)*7` takes that date, divides by 7 (b/c 7 days per week), rounds it down, then multiplies it by 7. This finds the Saturday before CEE. If CEE *is* a Saturday, then it returns that date.
- `(INT(~/7)*7+1-A2)/7` adds one to get Sunday, subtracts the input, and divides by 7 to get the number of weeks between the input and the Sunday before Christmas. This may not be a whole number.
- `4-(~)` subtracts that result from 4 to invert the result. I.E., the Sunday before Christmas needs to be the 4th Sunday, not the 1 week before.

```
LET(a,~,(LEN(a)=1)*(a<5)*a)
```

Now that the heavy lifting is out of the way, we can examine the results. Note that using TRUE and FALSE values in math will treat TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0. By multiplying various statements that will evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE, we can filter out undesirable results.

- `(LEN(a)=1)` filters out any non-integers as well as negative integers. This removes every non-Sunday in the advent calendar and all dates before the first Sunday. This does *not* filter out the 0th Sunday but the end result will still be 0 so it works.
- `(a<5)` filters out Sundays *after* the 4th Sunday.
- `(~)*(~)*a` returns the value if it has passed both those filters. Otherwise, it returns 0.

In this screenshot, I have added a column to return the value of `a` since that's so much of the calculation. I have also extended the data beyond the samples above to show some edge cases.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow. Another spreadsheet fan.

Comment: I'm just realising now that THIS IS SO UNDERRATED. Excel beat Mathematica!!!

Comment: You can get this down to 66 bytes if you use some implicit date conversion and Boolean multiplication as `=LET(a,4-(INT(("12/23/"&YEAR(A1))/7)*7+1-A1)/7,(a<5)*(LEN(a)=1)*a)` - but this will change the falsey output to be `0` rather than `false`

Comment: @TaylorRaine This is great! I haven't golfed in a while so the refresher course on Excel tricks is fantastic. I welcome your comments. I don't think I even knew about implicit date conversion.

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `calendar.holidays.us`, 85 bytes

```
[ <date> dup christmas-day 4 [ dup last-sunday ] times 0 5 narray reverse nip index ]
```

Takes input as three integers in <year> <month> <day> order. The `last-sunday` word postdates build 1525, the one TIO uses, so here's a screenshot of running the above code in build 2101's listener:

[image]

### Explanation

```
                             ! 2021 12 12
<date>                       ! 2021-12-12
dup                          ! 2021-12-12 2021-12-12
christmas-day                ! 2021-12-12 2021-12-25
4 [ dup last-sunday ] times  ! 2021-12-12 2021-12-25 2021-12-19 2021-12-12 2021-12-5 2021-11-28
0 5 narray                   ! 2021-12-12 2021-12-25 { 2021-12-19 2021-12-12 2021-12-5 2021-11-28 0 }
reverse                      ! 2021-12-12 2021-12-25 { 0 2021-11-28 2021-12-5 2021-12-12 2021-12-19 }
nip                          ! 2021-12-12 { 0 2021-11-28 2021-12-5 2021-12-12 2021-12-19 }
index                        ! 3
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 78 bytes

```javascript
(y,m,d)=>/Su/.test(c=new Date(y,m-1,d))*'01234'[(c-new Date(y,9,51))/6048e5|0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc2xCsIwEMbx3afI1kTS5i5pq0Xq5Bs4ikNJU1FqIzYqgu9eI0QQS4eb/j@@O1X3qtfX48XFna3N0JQDffIzr1m5FtubSJzpHdVlZx5kUznziTH6zOYRoFRptKM6/qkFz5AxkUO6NNkL9oO2XW9bk7T2QBsqQSInKDkhkrEVEYLAbESUz5m/fJqEFfyuqD@CRbHw2TMFgeBoBcOKzCYeKQAIBANJhzc)

Falsy may be 0 or NaN. Add 2 bytes (append `|0`) to always get 0. User must run this program with computer configured to UTC timezone or any other timezone that: 1. No DST shift during Nov 20 to Dec 31, 2. Name of timezone (in system language) does not contain substring `"Su"` (case sensitive).

`new Date(y,9,51)` is Nov 20 in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 152 bytes:

```
from datetime import*
t=lambda x:0if x>=date(x.year,12,25)else 1+t(x+timedelta(days=7))
f=lambda x:(s:=date(*x)).weekday()==6and(0<(j:=(5-t(s)))<5)and j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3LbsIwEEX3fMUsZyAg25GhWJgfQSxc2VEDeckZqc7XB1NUuom6mM0999wZJv7qu/JjiPNcxb4F7zhw3Qao26GPvF6xbVz76R0kI@oK0tk@K5h2U3CxkKpQmkIzBpAbxrR5uj407NC7abQHolX1t4CjeenrRLT7DuGeW0jW7l3nUZzwZizqLeNIRCdNOYXbPMS6Y6zwogrID0EJJa8XY7bymuffdF@A/oHlApT/u6XIWOY7Hg8LWOlfWy7ZSr5wKYR44/kB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 116 bytes

```
3=`
;
\d+
$*_
((_*)\2\2\2_*);((_*)\4\4\4_*)
$4$3$2$1$1$1$1$1
\G_{7}

-_{12}-
____
-_{11}-_{26}

^(_{7}){1,4}$|.+
$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3NCsJADITv8xqusK1Gkmx/KMVzX6K4FfTgpQfxVvfZ17TSDIRvJgN5Pz@v@Z6PfphyuE7oMT5OcGWE97EsRl1l0P9ttcoArnLBqZNdGIe4tAmguIgmQrTZjCTb2tjp5tdKsci5Su57sTcHyVlZhUSJFYaBuCZusKeikK5rSYQCWypbqjUCM28oPw) Link includes test cases. Takes input in ISO date format. Explanation:

```
3=`
;
```

Separate the year from the century.

```
\d+
$*_
```

Convert to unary.

```
((_*)\2\2\2_*);((_*)\4\4\4_*)
$4$3$2$1$1$1$1$1
\G_{7}
```

Perform Zeller's congruence on the 25th of December of the input year.

```
-_{12}-
____
-_{11}-_{26}
```

Add this to the day of the month, adding an extra 4 for December or subtracting 26 for November 26 or later. Other months get ignored and fail to match the next stage at all.

```
^(_{7}){1,4}$|.+
$#1
```

Count the number of whole weeks, but the result must be an integer between `1` and `4` inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/),  <s>88</s>  79 bytes

> Input format should be `{year, month, day}`.

```
Ramp[4-DayCount[#,{#&@@#,12,24},s=Sunday]]Boole[DayName@#==s&&Rest@#!={12,25}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xCsIwFEV3vyISyBQhSVulQyCos0gdY4aHBiyYVmw6lNJvjwl0qB3ecu657zrwL@vA1w8IXt5DBe6j890ZhlPbN15jOmKiFKZcUJFPtJO3vnnCYMyxbd9WR/ECziosZUdIZTuv8FaOyS4mQ8L1W8cvXo@CCU5R5EhMxmyWPKOooGi/xrPO/31elocIY5ixVSPBdGl5EWSMsXmZxyD8AA)

Output:

```
0
0
3
1
0
4
```

79 bytes - Thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)

Comment: [79 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY2xCsIwFEV3vyISyBQhSVulQyCos0gdY4aHBiyYVmw6lNJvjwl0qB3ecu657zrwL@vA1w8IXt5DBe6j890ZhlPbN15jOmKiFKZcUJFPtJO3vnnCYMyxbd9WR/ECziosZUdIZTuv8FaOyS4mQ8L1W8cvXo@CCU5R5EhMxmyWPKOooGi/xrPO/31elocIY5ixVSPBdGl5EWSMsXmZxyD8AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>215</s> <s>202</s></sup> 192 bytes

```c
#import<time.h>
i;*t;*l;f(d,m,y){5[t=calloc(9,8)]=y-1900;t[4]=m-1;t[3]=d;l=mktime(t);i=6[t=gmtime(&l)];y=t[7];t[4]=11;t[3]=25;l=mktime(t);d=7[t=gmtime(&l)]-y;m=4-d/7-!t[6];i=i|!d|m<1|m>4?0:m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLtbqMwEPyfp3Bz6glSc7EhH6WOcz9O9xQEnSLbpFYxRGDpwiV59aMLMVGpisx6vDOzXq0sgoMQbftNm2NZ2Y3VRv143U40m1k2y1nmSWxw45@XieVin@el8GL87Ke8CWhMCLPJIuUmoACilEuWc/PWFfGszzRfgetg@vP33E9Zw22yTm8m6jzhcmSSfD02BQ0zfBHI@Tp4sMkqhbL68iAvZkMvZrv4SV4Mu7a6sMjsdeH56DxB8HUJq2r7p0lSxNE5JCHFCGLUR8A0jtcdpoAjQsiVjY3mZqQhRktQw9Yp@z38rJXuEoxWN0lEoDTYQvpBqk5HJaxyYlDAgnZoDxZOKMqitki87qsZRCXeVHXTT3en3@HuFP@CfznF6OM5mjp3VlbI6@7ShVQnsBHm4AbV@p8qM2/owp@7xOyeYejpqVcPUxw6b6CSm2bPp2xEm4E2X9JyoOWXdA308NDGjALmPrTP1mMFksybPsp5v1CwRRAf610B02kwdIUlRjW@j7HmXKXuiuvk2v4XWb4/1G3w9x0)

*Saved 13 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!*

Inputs the day, month and year as separate parameters.
Returns which Advent Sunday it is or \$0\$ otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 114 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:(y:=int((c+10.5)/7))%5+y//5 if date(a,b,c).weekday()==6 and[b,c]!=[12,25]else 0
from datetime import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc1LCoMwEIDhvaeYLgqZGjSJRKuQk1gXUSMN9YUNFE9vrVjQ7Tf/zIyzew59dB@nxanH0uqurDVoWtIqI3OmbO8IqXzOAolhgniV/hyGEmwDtXaGbCUGH2NetZ4JKhWD7ut81eKici6okIVp3waY10xDt2052xmw3ThM7raM0@@HI4IJTmFdAIHoHTSiICnEZ9xTfmx5miYrraOInWr@PywPHDHGduaIyxc)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: You can make it 112 bytes by removing the space in `5 if` and `6 and[b,c]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/),  <s>128</s>  116 bytes

```python
lambda q:max(x*(date(*q)==(M:=date(q[0],11,27))+timedelta(7*x+~M.weekday()))for x in(1,2,3,4))
from datetime import*
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1LboMwEIb3OcXs4iHTyo8mBCRyg5yAsHCFUVBiHq6lwiZXJzals5pv/scMs7/3nToPbmmK2/LU9rvWMOZWT2xKWK29YcmIRcGuebHSWPKKhCCZIh58a01tnl6zNJkOr@vnrzGPWs8MEZvewQRtx4KXFH0h7hrXW4gtMQetHXrnkyUavfnxwQtlKbkUBEISyIogoiI4Epw22kSxqiLL0rCHm@J/uvgPHyMrzvnGoqryHYQZXNt5Fh8S7D8ue4JmJcTlDQ)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 144 bytes

```perl
sub{$_=join$",map{@t=gmtime$_*604800+3e5;19000100+$t[5]*1e4+$t[4]*100+$t[3]}1..6e4;pop=~/..../;/ $&$'( $&\d+)+/;$_=6-$&=~y///c/9;/^[1-4]$/?$_:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHbbsIwDIbv@xQWMhRoIYceRqkydj9p3OwOOrRBQN3Ww6BIQwhenbllgFYtURLbn2z/SXK9/vROuFSnzfZtjzP1nsUpNuzkNd8/FGqVFHGicdb1uTvg3HK0F4qAcy7IwWLiRV2h3dJyyTrHnOgg@n1fu2Ge5erI@jRYyABbaLZpny6sjsVC6uX3sKWOO8bYnAUhe5mInhshG@FsyA@n0Fhm67YBE5rSBkFLcikiUPfAIbLPxLcBvIo4f4mo5zgX4nAiglYQ3FVEXIh0auRaTXqXaqKmQIozcehVKuJetXk1BfKfan5N9aBGbtWoT3lbyfngltPZGwDJro2xjbqjHnAWVgHAFSho4ZJePFb0M5x3EeOJjCzxa4rIKg8S3Slz8nWcFstGcwMAcZpviyE0e8ItXf2d63mhFxQp3VVWss00bVBP0F/Ua2RmH@bQfBo/w/jRtCs1Nq5C43D6AQ)